# How do I install Laravel from phar file?

Tags: php, laravel, installation, laravel-4, phar

I downloaded the *laravel.phar* file, renamed it to *laravel*, moved it to */usr/local/bin*, then made it executable by all.

In my home directory, I tried `laravel new sandbox`, but nothing happens.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not bother renaming the file, and do not bother with /usr/local/bin. Just place laravel.phar in the folder where you are going to use it.

Then make sure you have the PHP curl module installed. On OpenSuse:

```
sudo zypper install php5-curl
```

Then create your new Laravel application with the following command (notice you use the php command to execute the .phar file):

```
php laravel.phar new <project-name>
```

e.g. `php laravel.phar new sandbox`. A new subfolder 
will be created with the project-name as its name, containing the skeleton of a Laravel application.

Comment: why laravel do not cover up this tiny information? that is so stupid!

Answer (score 4):

Or just run:

```
curl -O http://laravel.com/laravel.phar && chmod +x laravel.phar && mv laravel.phar /usr/local/bin/laravel
```

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me.

1. Create batch script and name it laravel.bat
2. Paste the following codes in your laravel.bat file

> @ECHO OFF
>
> php "%~dp0laravel.phar" %*

3.Store the laravel.bat file in the same directory as the downloaded PHAR file (laravel.phar)

4.Include the directory path in your environmental variables.

Then you are good to go.... just launch CMD and test it by typing laravel then hit return